# requireNativeComponent: 'RNSVGLinearGradient' was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

I installed react-native-chart-kit with the svg also and I got an error when I run the app. I have the basic code from the library site

[image]

```
<PieChart
data={data}
width={150}
height={220}
chartConfig={chartConfig}
accessor="population"
backgroundColor="transparent"
paddingLeft="15"
absolute
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you need to link it. Run the below and then build your app

> react-native link

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to link. Just make sure you have installed `react-native-svg` and then delete the App, restart the metro bundler and rebuilt the App again. Should work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

> yarn add react-native-svg

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with react-native-chart-kit's PieChart on ios. I solved it by doing 'pod install' in the ios directory, which installed RNSVG (12.3.0). It all worked fine after that, once I'd recompiled everything via Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

For me I installed following package for generating **QR CODES**.

```
npm install react-native-qrcode-sv
```

But above package is dependent on the bellow package

```
npm install react-native-svg
```

After installing **react-native-svg** my app running properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens when you don't rebuilt your native code after installing `react-native-svg`,
Just close all the running server and start again as...
`npx react-native run-android` for android or
`npx react-native run-ios` for ios

Or, if that doesn't help, open the project in xcode / android studio, clean the project, and rebuild.